# ASUS eeePC 1005PR - Installing Windows XP on this machine

Tags: windows-xp, installation, netbook, ahci

The machine in title is a single netbook .. with 1gb of ddr2. So Windows 7 kinda would be an overkill. I'd like  to install Windows XP on it, but as you may know, these small netbooks need special drivers.. like the AHCHI driver.

So:
 - First, I'll have to integrate the AHCI driver..with nLite into the ISO I suppose..
- Then , I'll have to create a bootable pendrive with XP..and THIS IS the hardest part.

Could you help me out? It's fine if you just point me go there, rtfm this, that...perfect.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinToFlash software for creating a bootable USB flash drive. Works with windows XP, Vista and Windows 7. It's still in beta but works great (in my experience) Visit their site: wintoflash.com/home/en/

If you want a step-by-step guide on how to do it, you can visit my site: http://www.edmartechguide.com/2009/09/how-to-install-windows-xp-using-usb.html

By the way, a 1gb memory netbook can handle windows 7.

Comment: Thanks.. one more huge question: And how do I integrate the AHCI driver? There is a PC in the house with the same problem. I can add the driver in nLite, but if I boot the PC, windows wont find any HDDs. I could use floppy..but on a netbook?... How do you do that?

Comment: Well..managed to fix it. Ty. :)